# How to create responsive, equal width, dynamic columns?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

This page can have three or two columns, depending on the content. When there are three columns, it should display all three columns for desktop then stack to one column on tablet and mobile. When there are two columns, it should display all two columns for desktop then stack to one column on tablet and mobile. But, I can't get it to do that. Instead, when there are three columns, at about 1200px, the third column wraps. So it ends up looking like this:

```
[1][2]
[3]
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="offers-wrap">
{% for offer in offers %}
 <div class="offer justify-evenly"></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.offers-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 350px));
  justify-content: center;
}

.offer {
  max-width: 28rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a media-query to your css that changes the width of your grid-columns to 100%. Like this:

```html
<style>
.offers-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 350px));
  justify-content: center;
}

.offer {
  max-width: 28rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1129px) {
  .offers-wrap {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 100%));
  }
}

</style>

<div class="offers-wrap">
   <div class="offer justify-evenly">
     test
   </div>
   <div class="offer justify-evenly">
     test
   </div>
   <div class="offer justify-evenly">
     test
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up expanding a little on what Yannick H has

```
.offers-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 100%));
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .offers-wrap {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 275px));
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .offers-wrap {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 375px));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do what you ask:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, beacon, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, inArray, shuffle, isNum, isInt, rand;
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, func, responseType = 'json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
  }
  x.onerror = e=>{
    if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = function(url, send, func, responseType ='json', context = null){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    const c = context || x;
    x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
    x.onload = ()=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
    }
    x.onerror = e=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
    }
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    x.send(d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
beacon = function(url, send){
  let r = false;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    r = nav.sendBeacon(url, d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return r;
}
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = function(node, className){
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
inArray = (mixed, array)=>{
  if(array.indexOf(mixed) === -1){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
isNum = mixed=>typeof mixed === 'number' && !isNaN(mixed); isInt = mixed=>Number.isInteger(mixed);
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// above is a library for you to learn - below is mobile test
const wrap = I('wrap');
if(mobile){
  aC(wrap, 'mobile');
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  background:#ccc; margin:0;
}
#wrap{
  display:grid; grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr); grid-auto-rows:auto; height:100vh;
}
#wrap.mobile{
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2, 1fr);
}
#wrap>div{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:100%; background:#fff; 
}
#wrap>div:nth-child(odd){
  background:#000; color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='wrap'>
    <div><div>one</div></div>
    <div><div>two</div></div>
    <div><div>three</div></div>
    <div><div>four</div></div>
    <div><div>five</div></div>
    <div><div>six</div></div>
    <div><div>seven</div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I put a small JavaScript library in there so you can see how to reduce code. The library also does a simple mobile test, as well. Also, notice that I had to add another `<div>` within your content `<div>`s, so I could align the text too. You'll notice that the actual JavaScript to accomplish the adding of an HTML class with `aC` is under the `// above is a library for you to learn - below is mobile test` comment.